# Using assign in pandas with time series data and groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to assign a new column to an existing pandas data frame `mydf`. The series to be added is the result from evaluating an expression that is passed as a string. The expression can contain python function calls, for instance:

```
formula = 'myfunction(mydf.v1)'
```

`myfunction` is as follows

```
def myfunction(series):
    return recursive_filter(series, 0.1)
```

The following code will evaluate the expression and execute `myfunction` and assign the column `v2` to `mydf`

```
mydf.assign(v2 = eval(formula))
```

However, I need to execute the function by `Market`. The output should look like the table below

```
Market      Date          v1    v2
UK          2013-01-01    10   10.00
UK          2013-01-02    10   11.00 
UK          2013-01-03    10   11.10
UK          2013-01-04    10   11.11
US          2013-01-01    10   10.00
US          2013-01-02    10   11.00
US          2013-01-03    10   11.10
US          2013-01-04    10   11.11
```

I tried the following code (which I'm not sure would produce the correct result...)

```
mydf.groupby('CrossSection').apply(mydf.assign(v2 = eval(formula)))
```

However this produces this error

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems you are having is that the formula hardcodes the DataFrame to apply it to, i.e. `mydf`.

Anyways, here's something that should work. I couldn't find a way to not created another dataframe, but if your dataset isn't terribly big it shouldn't matter much.

I rewrote the formula to accept a string formatting of which dataframe to apply it to.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.filters.filtertools import recursive_filter

formula = 'myfunction({}.v1)'
def myfunction(series):
    return recursive_filter(series, 0.1)

df2 = mydf.groupby('Market').apply(lambda df: df.assign(v2 = eval(formula.format("df"))))
df2.index = df2.index.droplevel(level=0)
df2
```

Result:

```
  Market        Date  v1     v2
0     UK  2013-01-01  10  10.00
1     UK  2013-01-02  10  11.00
2     UK  2013-01-03  10  11.10
3     UK  2013-01-04  10  11.11
4     US  2013-01-01  10  10.00
5     US  2013-01-02  10  11.00
6     US  2013-01-03  10  11.10
7     US  2013-01-04  10  11.11
```